# Is $(\forall x\in \mathbb R)(\exists y\in \mathbb R):(x^2<y^2)$. true? And How would I negate this statement?

Tags: logic

$(\forall x\in\mathbb R)(\exists y\in\mathbb R)(x^2<y^2)$. From my understanding, this statement is False, but I'm not too sure. And I don't know how to negate it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $y=x^2+1$.$\;\;$Then
$$x^2 < x^2+(x^4+x^2+1)=x^4+2x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2=y^2$$
hence for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 < y^2$.

Another argument . . .

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and choose $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|y| >|x|$.

Since the function $f(t)=t^2$ is strictly increasing for $t\ge 0$, we get
$$
x^2=|x|^2 < |y|^2 = y^2
$$
with the same conclusion as before.

Note that in proving the given statement, we let $x$ be an unrestricted unknown real number, but in showing the existence of $y$ satisfying the specified condition, we are allowed to define $y$ in terms of $x$.

As regards the negation of the given statement, try putting it in words . . .

To state that it is not true that

  For all $x$, there exists $y$ such that [the condition]

is equivalent to saying

  There is some $x$ for which there does not exist $y$ such that [the condition]

which can be reworded as

  There is some $x$ such that for all $y$ we have [negation of the condition]

and note that the negation of the condition $(x^2 < y^2)$ is simply $(x^2\ge y^2)$.

Symbolically, the statement
$$
\lnot\bigl(\,\forall x,\exists y\;\colon P(x,y)\bigr)
\;\;\;\;\;\;
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\exists x,\forall y\;\colon\lnot P(x,y)
$$
Can you now construct the negation?

Comment: Great! And how would I negate this statement?

Comment: I've edited in some discussion of the negation.